# Cannot access 'java.lang.Object' which is a supertype of 'com.jitendra.sdk.android.gradle.quality.QualityToolsPlugin'

Tags: java, android, object, gradle, lang

I upgraded to gradle 7.02 and i have this error : can not access java.lang.object

what's possible reason ?

I already tried.

1. Invalidate cache and restart.
2. deleting build, .gradle, .idea file ..
   still no luck.

[image: 1] gradle 7

Comment: 1. check the project jdk and gradle settings   (not sure what you use wrapper or local)
2. did the project reimport go through ?

Comment: 1. settings.gradle.kts
include(":quality-tools")
for gradle i am using wrapper .
I have created gradle plugins using 5 plugins : Android Lint, checkstyle,PMO,Spotbugs,Detekt.

I have created wrapper of [JaCoCo] plugin for creating code coverage reports for testing. 

My final objective : solve codecoverage  test cases error which is failing beacause of import error of java.io.File  
complete details : 
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-48853